# Reading RAW DNG files in android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera2

I am using the new Camera 2 API, specifically referring to Camera2Raw example provided by google to save my image as a DNG file. However, I do want to read this DNG file and process it in the next activity.

From what I have read online, We don't have any direct method to read the file. My approach was to use the Exif data using ExifInterface class to get the width and the height and then use the stream of data as the input and make an encoder for the RAW image.

However, the ExifData was null for the DNG file. Does android set the data or do I need to do anything different at the CaptureRequest? The JPEG encoded image for the same had a lot of information.

How do I got about ensuring that the metadata for the DNG image is complete? Thanks. And is there an easier way to read the DNG file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using right the `DngCreator` class from `Camera2` Api all your metadata should be fine, just remember to set the orientation and the width/height values that you got from your `Image` item on your `ImageReader`  callback.

If you want to check the metadata of the DNG files you should use a programm as Adobe Photoshop or Adboe LightRoom(for your phone device). Anyway in Android N you will be able to detect DNG files with the `MediaScanner` class if I'm not wrong.